# Is there anyway to simplify my jQuery Selector code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can you help me simplify this selector.

Here is the code:

```
$("input[name='grpQuestion1'], input[name='grpQuestion2'], input[name='grpQuestion4']").change(function (event) {
    /* Some code here */ 
});
```

Comment: you need to use single quotes around your selectors (or around the names, either way)  - I know that's not the question, just saying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in the comments that you need specifically the three names, so

```
 var names = ['grpQuestion1', 'grpQuestion2', 'grpQuestion4'];
 $.each(names, function(i, v) { 
   $('input[name='+v+']').change(function (event) {
        /* Some Code Here */ 
   });
 });
```

would make it a bit easier to maintain.

Comment: `i` is a key (integer, ex: 0,1,2,...), `v` is value of array (object type like: grpQuestion1, grpQuestion2,...)

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
$('input[name^="grpQuestion"]').change(function (event) { /* Some Code Here */ });
```

jquery has some attribute selection

like `$("[attribue^=value]")` elements which attribute starts with value word.
`$("[attribue$=value]")` elements which attribute ends with value word.
`$("[attribue*=value]")` elements which attribute contain value as a part or a word or exact word.
`$("[attribue~=value]")` elements which attribute contain value as exact word

Comment: I need the name to be specifically grpQuestion1, grpQuestion2, grpQuestion4 only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name^="grpQuestion"]').change(/** your code */)
```

What it does is basically select all elements that start with "grpQuestion"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('input[name^="grpQuestion"]').change(function (event) { /* Some Code Here */ });
```

***means***

input start with name="grpQuestion"

Comment: @Eblaster is that working for you?

Comment: if modification needed please inform.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name^=grpQuestion]").change(function (event) {
/* Some Code Here */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the first four input elements that have a name attribute beginning with 'grpQuestion', you can use the following jQuery selector:

```
$('input[name^="grpQuestion"]:lt(4)')
```